# how to align footer in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, footer

please visit the link : http://steel.newtrendzonline.com/

Please see the footer. I want to display "NEWTRENDZ NZ LIMITED" in the same line as above line.

Below is my code in system=>configuration => footer

http ://pastebin.com/v6Jr9mX7

© 2014 STEEL OFFCUTS. All Rights Reserved. Designed by

[NEWTRENDZ NZ LIMITED](http://www.newtrendz.co.nz/)

.

but i can't able to bring " NEWTRENDZ NZ LIMITED " to above line.

Please give me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <p align="left" id="nav" style="font-size:19px; color:white; "><span style="
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
">© 2014 STEEL OFFCUTS. All Rights Reserved. Designed by</span>  
<a href="http://www.newtrendz.co.nz/" style="padding: 0px;"> 
NEWTRENDZ NZ LIMITED</a>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks, how i can increase the footer background-height?